# Source transformation question

Tags: current

I'm having some trouble finding the Thevenin equivalent circuit for a circuit that has a parallel independent current source before the voltage accross a connected circuit, as in the image.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: transform and combine. done. you literally posted the solution as your question. If you have an actual question/issue you should post that instead of being vague.

Answer (score 1):

Like they did in the solution given.

First transform the 12 V /  4 kOhm to Norton form.

Now you have two current sources in parallel, so you can combine them by algebraicly summing their currents and replacing them with a single source.

Now convert your Norton circuit back to Thevenin.

Comment: in particular I was wondering how they were able to surmise that the equivalent Thevenin circuit for the 12v open voltage and 4kiliohm resistor would be one with -3mA current and a 2kiliohm resistance in parallel.

Comment: @Duderdyde, that looks like an error. The Norton shunt element should be 4 kohms, and the Norton source should be 12 V / 4 kOhm = 3 mA (which they got right).

Comment: oh man I've been trying to figure out how they made that conclusion for so long. I feel pretty silly. Thanks for the help.